# How to fill missing data in large dataframe from other rows for the same id/person?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [{'a':2,'b': 2, 'c':3},{'b': 2, 'c':np.nan}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}, {'a': 10, 'b': np.nan, 'c': np.nan}]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['John', 'John', 'Mike' ,'Mike'])
```

What I am trying to do is to fill the missing data of every user.

My goal dataframe would be:

```
data = [{'a':2,'b': 2, 'c':3},{'a':2, 'b': 2, 'c':3}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['John', 'John', 'Mike' ,'Mike'])
```

Now this should be applied for thousands of rows, but I believe this minimalistic example should be fine to accomplish that in a big dataframe.

I do not want to use pd.merge since this would add thousands of columns to my dataframe since my original dataframes have that amount of columns

Comment: What determines the valid value to fill the NaNs? If you want the one right before it, you could use `ffill()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform('first')` to extract the first valid values for each user, then `fillna`:

```
df = df.fillna(df.groupby(level=0).transform('first'))
```

**Note**: You can

1. replace `'first'` with other functions, e.g. `'mean'` if you like.
2. apply the function directly instead of `transform`: `groupby().first()`, since you are grouping based on index.

Comment: thanks, but what about if a want to fill string values instead of integers? I tried with strings but is not working. Cheers

Comment: First should work with strings,unless you have empty strings instead of np.nan

Comment: ok thank you! I consider this as solutio